# Sharepoint Infopath multiple selection listbox with dynamic conditional list-options

Tags: sharepoint, infopath, infopath2010, infopath-2007

In sharepoint infopath (2013) how do I create a multiple selection listbox with list-options which depend on a criteria?

Example: My MSLB should load with 4 list-options. However if the user chooses option-2, then a 5th list-option should be displayed (or enabled) in the same MSLB. Is it possible

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on something similar to this. What I've done is separate the conditions from the result in sections and used rules to hide/show the respective section based on the condition that is met/not met. Hope this helps
[Conditional Section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6hv6.png)